# How to parse 380K html pages (best way in terms of performance)?

Tags: html, r, performance, xml-parsing, html-parsing

What do I have:

- 380,000 html pages (acticles from news portal from 2010 to 2017).
- 65.19Gb (68,360,000Kb) total.
- 170Kb per page (in average).
- Server 1: 2.7GHz i5, 16Gb Ram, SSD, macOS 10.12, R version 3.4.0 (my laptop).
- Server 2: 3.5GHz Xeon E-1240 v5, 32Gb, SSD, Windows Server 2012, R
  version 3.4.0.

What do I need:

- I need to parse those html pages and get the data that looks like:
  ArticleDate | ArticleSection | ArcticleTitle | ArticleAuthor |
  ArticleContent| ... |

What do I do:

```
require(rvest)
files <- list.files(file.path(getwd(), "data"), full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE, pattern = "index")
downloadedLinks <- c()
for (i in 1:length(files)) {
  currentFile <- files[i]
  pg <- read_html(currentFile, encoding = "UTF-8")
  fileLink <- html_nodes(pg, xpath=".//link[@rel='canonical']") %>% html_attr("href")   
  downloadedLinks <- c(downloadedLinks, fileLink)  
}
```

I run this code on 40,000 pages and got this result:

- Server 1: 800secs
- Server 2: 1000secs

It means it will take 7600secs or **126mins to process 380,000 pages on Server 1** and **9500secs or 158mins on Server 2**

Because of that I have few questions and hope that community will help me. I will be glad to hear any ideas, suggestions or critics.

1. How can I improve my code above to reduce processing time?
2. Why Server 2 (I mean real server) shows low performance comparing to Server 1 (my laptop)?
3. Is there a way to order Server 2 to use more CPU and RAM (it is about 10% CPU usage and 300Mb RAM for Rgui.exe process)

Comment: I would suggest you checked the 'foreach' and `doParallel` packages. Check the following link https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doParallel/vignettes/gettingstartedParallel.pdf out

Comment: Also make sure you include all the necessary packages in your example! I also found another link that might help: https://beckmw.wordpress.com/tag/foreach/

Comment: I agree with @amonk. If something can easily shorten your time is foreach and doParallel. However, if the largest proportion of time is needed for reading from disk, parallelization will not help (I think). In that case, a (horrible) workaround would be to split the work between two servers using different disk resource, and then merging the final results.

Comment: I tried to used foreach package a while ago. As I understand I can improve my code 2 times if I have 2 cores and 4 times if I have 4 cores? Anyway I will look to that package again and try to apply it. I will get back here with the result.

Comment: I think it is mostly about reading from disk and this line pg <- read_html(currentFile, encoding = "UTF-8"). I run my sample just with this line in the loop and got almost same result. Does it means I will not get performance improvement with foreach?

Comment: I have one more options in my mind. I can break down my files in 10 groups (40,000 in each), create 10 scripts and run them at one time (one by one in different R sessions). I will get 10 results and will combine that results in 1 file. I believe it will take about 800-1000secs. But I think it will not be a "nice code" and it will be not "reproducible research".

Comment: The first problem is that even if you run independent R sessions, time will not decrease, because the bottleneck is in the disk. Reproducibility is not an issue because you can write a wrapper command that from the beginning read the full list, split it, and then merge the results.

Comment: To better understand which part of your code is the most expensive in terms of time passed you could benchmark parts of it with `microbenchmark::microbenchmark` or use something like `profvis`.